# Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 + Maven : Could not determine type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Using Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE with Hibernate 4.3.5.Final, when i try to make a relation between to entities, even the simplest ones fails with this error :

Could not determine type for: com.mobistech.drc.m2mproject.pojo.Test2, at table: Test1, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(test2)]

Here are classes :

**Test1.java**

```
    package com.mobistech.drc.m2mproject.pojo;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;


    @Entity
    public class Test1 {

        private int id;

        private Test2 test2;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }


        @JoinColumn(name = "id")
        public Test2 getTest2() {
            return test2;
        }

        public void setTest2(Test2 test2) {
            this.test2 = test2;
        }
    }
```

Test2.java

```
package com.mobistech.drc.m2mproject.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Test2 {

    private int id;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

I've already tried to moving annotations to the top of properties... It didn't work either...

Here are maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

** EDIT **
Configuration :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mobistech.drc.m2mproject" />


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/drc" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="blabla" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>

            <value>com.mobistech.drc.m2mproject.pojo.Test1</value>
            <value>com.mobistech.drc.m2mproject.pojo.Test2</value>

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Post your configuration. You would also need a `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` instead (or next to) the `@JoinColumn`.

Comment: what if Test2 should not be aware of Test1 ?

Comment: Why would that be the case you can have  a perfectly uni-directional relationship with a `@ManyToOne`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@JoinColumn(name = "test2_id", referencedColumnName = "id")`

Your join column definition should be like above...
also you have to declare a `@OneToOne` relation

Comment: did you add the relation annotation? @paroxit

Comment: I didn't now that. I'm new to java. Thank you... I thought hibernate could map between those 2 objects without me declaring it since its just a One-to-One...

Comment: I recommend you to read a tutorial then, you can find good informations. example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/  hibernate site itself: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/

Comment: Thats the strange thing. I actually read tons of articles about. No one mentioned it ...  Like this one : http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-hibernate-4-gradle-integration-example-using-annotation

Comment: That's because in that tutorial there is only one entity with no relationships to other entities.